# How to get kubernetes GPC output IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ip

I have kubernetes cluster in google cloud.

I have an external database and I need to set trusted IP range in database.

My problem is, that I don't know what outgoing ip is from my kubernetes.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're finding the source IP of outgoing packets from kubernetes to be trusted by the external database.

1. When outgoing packets are [source NAT'ed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#terminology), the source IP is usually the node's IP.
2. There is a way to [preserve source IP address](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip) and not do source NAT'ing by using the `service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy` field in the service manifest. Note this risks potentially imbalanced traffic spreading.

   ```
   "externalTrafficPolicy": "Local"
   ```

   Note `"externalTrafficPolicy": "Local"` had issues with `NodePort` service type in earlier k8s versions due to the following bugs:

   - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52096
   - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58338
   - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57922

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to the cluster from outside you have to create `Service`. When you will create it, you will automatically receive `External-IP` address which you can use to connect to your cluster from outside. You can check [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) how to create `service`.
You can also create `endpoints` (depends on your needs) if you need more than one IP address.

Later you will just need to execute `kubectl get service -o wide`. You will receive output like:

```
$ kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
connection-to-my-db   LoadBalancer   10.0.3.84    34.76.XXX.148   8080:32165/TCP   84s   run=nginx
kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.0.0.1     <none>          443/TCP          17d   <none>
```

However, for a wile `External-IP` from that service will be in  state. You just need to wait 1-2 minutes to received it.

As you are using GCP you can read [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services) article about mapping external services.